# Service in angularJS doesn`t work. Asp.Net Core

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I created the simple MVC project on ASP.NET Core 2.0 with one view where I start all my angularJS work. I have a problem with services. It doesn't matter inject the service on app.run or not, I always have mistake.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/home.html',
    authenticate: false
  });
});

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'TestServices', 
  function ($rootScope, $state, TestServices) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
      function (event, toState, toParams) {
        console.log(toState.authenticate);
        //need run service method here!
      }
    );
  }
]);
```

My service

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.service('TestServices', function () {

 this.cal = function() {
    console.log("Heloo")
  }

});
```

I dodnt know what a problem. I tried evryhing. I can`t call the method from the services. I inject it everywhere but without result. i cant call any method from my services!

Index page cshtml

```
@{
Layout = null;
 }

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"> 
</script>
<script src="~/app/pages/TaxFactory.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui- 
  router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<script src="~/app/pages/app.js"></script>
</head>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
<div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Here the link for the project if you need it.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dg8zcGEySUU8UbsL339B-gZgr7QrsNDF
I think it something with ui-router and cshtml format such as startpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding app variable in app.js. So TestService is no more available.

One way to avoid this, change TaxFactory.js as;

```
var taxFactory = function () {
    this.cal = function () {
        console.log("Heloo");
    };
};
```

And add this line before `app.run` in app.js;

`app.service('TestServices', taxFactory);`

Comment: sorry, but without result ...  http://prntscr.com/meh5s9  http://prntscr.com/meh62h

Comment: You are putting the 'TestServices' references in wrong place. Should be on `app.run()` https://ibb.co/8BhdQky

Comment: Didnt understand, but it is on app.run on screenshot

Comment: On your screenshot it is on $rootScope.on. the one I commented earlier, it is on app.run. If you change your code as screenshot I sent, it will work. I've tried in my local, it is working.

Comment: Thanks!! It is works!!! And if you have a time, tell me please. Why it did not work such in all example where I make app.service in other file. How I can do it by normal practice?